# When product is purchased in StoreKit I get: "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I have looked at many different possible solutions to this problem but none of them work. I have tried implementing in app purchases in a few different ways and I keep on getting the same error. Are there any solutions to this problem? As soon as I click a button that is supposed to charge me I get this error before it even asks me for my apple id.

Comment: Are you testing on the Simulator? That won't work.

Comment: No, real device.

Comment: Did you enter test account into iCloud info on device? Are you running from Xcode? TestFlight?

Comment: yeah runninit on a physcial device. Xcode & testfliht, but it wont workout

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest iOS version, preferably >= 14.0, If that doesn't solve the issue checkout their latest storekit doc where they have explained a new way to setup store products right from XCode for local testings.